# How can I put WebBrowser display behind my control?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, browser

I am trying to make a menu on top of WebBrowser control, so when user select it, it will tell the WebBrowser to go centain page.

So I did something like:

```
<Grid x:Name="Root">
    <WebBrowser Name="_WebBrowser" Source="http://google.ca" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"></WebBrowser>    
    <Expander Name="expander1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="250" ExpandDirection="Right" IsExpanded="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
```

Far as I know, the last define control should be on top...

But strange, the WebBrowser will always display on top....and it covers my Expander (menu).
I tried to put WebBrowser inside a Carvas or even Button lol  But the WebBrowser it is still display on the top....

I hope this is not a bug in .NET 3.5.....

Comment: You need to define grid rows and columns and place the controls in the appropriate row and column.

Comment: @BalamBalam Even if I define the row and column, it still has the same issue. When I  replace WebBrowser with other Control in this code, it just work fine.

Comment: An alternative WPF web browser control is Awesomium (http://awesomium.com/).  Is this of interest to you?

Comment: @LukeWoodward Sounds awesome~ I am going it out when I got office on monday! Thanks! Just got to pray it support .NET 3.5....

Comment: Sadly, it seems Awesomium only supports .NET 4: http://support.awesomium.com/discussions/questions/549-net-35-version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is this is a limitation of WPF.

The `WebBrowser` control is simply a managed wrapper around the Windows COM component, which has its own window handle.  For this reason, you're not able to draw over it.

More details: [WPF 3.5 WebBrowser control and ZIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83319/wpf-3-5-webbrowser-control-and-zindex)