# Is it possible to overlap WPF WebBrowser with other UIElement?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uielement

I want to put over WPF WebBrowser some `UIElement` (opacity = 0) ie and catch all click events via this overplaced `UIElement`.

Is it possible to do?

This code doesn't work...

```
<Canvas Name="cnsMain">
  <WebBrowser x:Name="MainBrowser" Visibility="Visible" Panel.ZIndex="0" />
  <Canvas Panel.ZIndex="100" Opacity="0.01"></Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Seems trivial to try.  Did you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I put WebBrowser display behind my control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039593/how-can-i-put-webbrowser-display-behind-my-control)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the WPF Webbrowser is just the standard browser control in a WPF wrapper. It is not native WPF and therefore does not respect the `ZOrder` of WPF apps.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do it with the WPF WebBrowser that originally ship with SDK.
It always on top of other `UIElement`.

But I think it is possible with 3rd party control.

For detail take a look in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039593/how-can-i-put-webbrowser-display-behind-my-control) I asked before.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This can be done in .NET 4.5.  It requires setting the following properties on your `WebBrowser` control **before** it is ever rendered:</strike>

```
IsRedirected = true
CompositionMode = System.Windows.Interop.CompositionMode.Full
```

This will enable hwnd redirection, allowing the normal top-level hwnd used for rendering to be redirected to a WPF surface that can play nice with other elements in your tree.

**EDIT:** It would seem this feature was yanked out of .NET 4.5 prior to release.  My apologies if I gave anyone false hope.  Thanks to @JoeDaley for pointing out my error.

Comment: Thank you to share your answer!

Comment: Where are these properties? They don't exist on my .NET 4.5 WebBrowser control, and all I can find searching the net are posts from 2012 about how these properties were removed from .NET 4.5 before its final release. http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2644120-bring-back-the-hwndhost-isredirected-and-compositi

Comment: @JoeDaley Whoops, it would seem you are correct.  Funny that nobody caught that until now.