# Can't put any elements on top of web browser

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015

I have been trying different way of arranging my elements in my application but no matter what I do I cannot set my stackpanel on top of a web browser element. Is there any way to accomplish this?

I have tried setting the order of the items and even manually adjusting the z-index. I've also tried a couple different grid layouts but still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't , WebBrowser it's a wrapper around the IE COM Control and you can't put anything on it.

Comment: You can also check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039593/how-can-i-put-webbrowser-display-behind-my-control