# Why is the GeckoFX Web Browser always on top? How do I tell it to respect the hierarchy?

Tags: wpf, gecko, geckofx

**Summary of what I intend to do:**

I have a grid called `VideoContainerGrid` which gets filled with a GeckoFX Web Browser through the view model. It's navigating towards an embedded YouTube video. What I wanted to do was show a grid with a few buttons as tools (i.e. for speeding up the video, etc) if the `RootGrid` receives a MouseOver.

**The Problem:**

For some reason, the GeckoFX Web Browser is staying on top of everything I put over it, even if the grid that I want to show on top is higher than grid that houses the browser.

**Simplified Code:** (I've already handled the MouseOver events and just simplified the code below for clarity)

```
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
    <Grid x:Name="VideoContainerGrid"/>
    <Grid x:Name="GridIWantToShowOnTop"/>
</Grid>
```

**Another solution I tried:** (Applying the Z index explicitly)

```
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
    <Grid x:Name="VideoContainerGrid"   Panel.ZIndex="1"    />
    <Grid x:Name="GridIWantToShowOnTop" Panel.ZIndex="9999" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could there be some property on the Gecko Web Browser that tells it to stay on top of everything?

Comment: Is this a similar issue to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83319/wpf-3-5-webbrowser-control-and-zindex ?

Comment: I also saw an interesting workaround on the comments. The person saved the current frame as an image and hid the browser and showed the former instead whenever he would need something to show up above the browser. The only problem I see with this approach is that I'm dealing with a video that's constantly playing frames and I would have to constantly pump out different frames for it to look seamless. I can, however, pause the video instead on mouse enter and just save the last frame as the background while hiding the web browser. I'll try the first approach first and see if I can handle it.